# glade gtk+2 and gtk+3

Tags: gtk, gtk2, gtk3

I have Gtk+3 already installed as it was with the distro. I need to use gtk+2 and glade. How do I use glade with gtk+2 and still have both gtk2 and gtk3 installed on my linux box?

I have Glade 3.12.2 installed and when I save a project then open it in a text file it shows gtk 3 and need for it to say gtk 2 not gtk 3.

Answer (score 2):

i use Linux Mint and i've installed 2 Glade:

- Glade 3.8.0
- Glade 3.14.2

If i use Glade 3.8.0, after saving a project i get this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.24"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

So, maybe, solution for you is install also Glade 3.8.0

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to guarantee that glades made for gtk2 will be compatible with gtk3?